# displaying the last record of the field in a input box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have php form which I used to input Members Details of my system into the database. My requirement is to display the last member's 'member id' in a input box. When I try the following code it gives me the 'member id' of all the members in a select box. Please correct my php coding to display only the 'member id' of the last member.

php coding

```
  $dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  $db = mysql_select_db("MemberDB",$con);

  $sqlselect = "SELECT MemID FROM Member" ;
  $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sqlselect);
```

html coding

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>display the last member id</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="memid" name="memid1">  
            <option>Select Member ID</option>";
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
                <option><?php echo $row[1];?></option>";
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </select>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `SELECT` query, this is from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp):

```
SELECT MemID FROM Member
ORDER BY MemID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will order your data in descending order, then get the topmost data from that order.